# Let $f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ where $f^{-1}([0,a))$ and $f^{-1}((b,1])$ are open sets in $X$ prove $f$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ where $f^{-1}([0,a))$ and $f^{-1}((b,1])$ are open sets in $X$ for each $0<a,b<1$ prove $f$ is continuous

The problem with question it's not clear which topology defined on $[0,1]$, So I assumed it's subspace from standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$

---

My Attempt:

It's sufficient to prove that $f^{-1}$ for each base element  in $[0,1]$ element is an open set in $X$
So any bases of $[0,1]$ will be in this form:

- $(a,b)\cap [0,1]= [0,1], \ 1<b \  \& a<0 $
- $(a,b)\cap [0,1]= [0,b), \ 0<b<1 \  \& a<0 $
- $(a,b)\cap [0,1]= (a,1], \ 1<b \  \& 1>a>0 $
- $(a,b)\cap [0,1]= (a,b), \ 1>b>a \  \& a>0 $
- $(a,b)\cap [0,1]= \phi, \ 1<a<b\  or\ a<b<0  $

If we examine continuity condition for each case it will be satisfied for instance:

$f^{-1}((a,b))=f^{-1}([0,b)\cap (a,1])=f^{-1}([0,b))\cap f^{-1}((a,1])$ by hypothesis in question $f^{-1}([0,b))$ and $f^{-1}((a,1])$ is open, therefore their intersections are open. So $f$ is continuous.

Am I in correct path?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a more direct approach. The sets $(-\infty, a)$,  $(b,\infty)$ form a subbase for the topology on  $\Bbb R$, so the sets  $[0, a)$ and $(b, 1]$ form a subbase for the subspace topology on the interval.  By hypothesis the preimages of subbase sets are open, so $f$ is continuous.  That's a general fact, but it is proved with the same argument that you are using in your last step.